# WAV / MP3 Conversion On Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mp3, wav, file-conversion

I'm looking to convert uploaded WAV files to MP3 on my shared hosting server (ASP.NET / C#) and am curious if anyone else has tackled this before.

I've seen a few open source C# libraries for performing audio conversion (AumpLib, for example), but in most cases it looks like people are using them on desktop applications.

Are there any good open source C# libraries / technologies for this scenario?  Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried LAME? http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: lame is best if you are converting to high vbr mp3 otherwise there are others that are faster or better - (http://mp3.radified.com/audio_codec_comparison.htm )

Answer (score 2):

The [BASS Library](http://www.un4seen.com) can perform encoding to MP3. It is not open source, but it will do the job nicely. There's also a .NET wrapper available.